# What is the type of a variadic function in Typed Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, variadic-functions, typed-racket

I'm attempting to convert a Racket program that uses the f32vector from ffi/vector into a Typed Racket program, which requires providing annotations for f32vector via require/typed. f32vector is however variadic; it can take a variable number of arguments, so both of the following are acceptable:

```
(f32vector 1.0 3.0 4.0 7.0)
(f32vector 2.0 2.1)
```

How would I write the type annotations for this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you already have an opaque type for `F32Vector`, then you can write the type like this:

```
(require/typed ffi/vector
               [f32vector (Real * -> F32Vector)])
```

In case you don't have an opaque type yet, you can import that like this:

```
(require/typed ffi/vector
               [#:opaque F32Vector f32vector?])
```

Of course, you can merge the clauses above into a single `require/typed`.

---

Side note: in the future, Typed Racket will probably also support a `->*` type constructor that matches the notation used for writing contracts (including rest arguments). Also, hopefully we can provide a `typed/ffi/vector` along with the other bundled libraries.

Comment: You might want to use `Float` or even `Single-Float` instead of `Real` here.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. It might be useful to add this to the Typed Racket documentation sometime, or make it easier to find if it's already there.

Comment: No problem. The Typed Racket guide does explain this syntax in section 4.8.1, but maybe it's not clear enough or easy to find. If you have any suggestions on how to improve it, please feel free to file a change request, write to the mailing list, or ping one of us on IRC.

Comment: @AsumuTakikawa Oops, I missed it when I was reading that section of the guide. For some reason I was trying to use the ... notation instead of the *. My fault; the guide itself is pretty clear.

Comment: @AsumuTakikawa just added support for these vectors. 

https://github.com/plt/racket/compare/2b9b16b165...11bfdce685

You can grab a new version of Racket here: http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/snapshots/